# Django - formatting json objects

Tags: python, json, django, d3.js

I am working on a backend web service using Django to consume JSON for later be displayed in a map using d3.js. The problem is that I am having trouble to parsing the json in the way I need. This is the format I get right now:

```
{
  "UT": [    
      {"score": "Republican"},
      {"recurrence": 32}
  ],
  "WI": [
      {"score": "Democrat"},
      {"recurrence": 32}
  ]
}
```

And this is the format I need:

```
{
  "UT": {
      "score": "5.01",
      "recurrence": 32
  },
  "WI": {
      "score": 4.92,
      "recurrence": 32
  }
}
```

The function I am using is this one:

```
def StatesJson(request, word):

    states = State.objects.filter(word__word=word)
    states_dict = dict()

    for state in states:
        states_dict[state.state] = ({"score": state.score},{"recurrence": state.recurrence})

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(states_dict))
```

There is any way to get rid of the square brackets?

Comment: LOL It was easier than I thought. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it without calling replace:

```
states_dict[state.state] = {"score": state.score, "recurrence": state.recurrence}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about a little `replace` (assuming your JSON is a variable called `data`):

`data.replace("[", "{").replace("]", "}")`

Comment: This would result in invalid JSON.  You are converting JSON arrays to objects, but the objects need a key and value for each entry.